# Computing $[T]_\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$, $T(a,b)=\begin{pmatrix} 10a-6b\\17a-10b\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $\beta$={$(1,2),(2,3)$}.

Where $T$ is a linear operator on $V$ and $\beta$ is an ordered basis. I have to compute $[T]_\beta$ and  determine whether $\beta$ is a basis consisting of eigenvectors for $T$.

I know this is probably very simple, but by book's explanation remains unclear. I just need to know how to compute $[T]_\beta$, I can figure out the eigenvectors part.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$T(1,2)=(10-12, 17-20)=(-2,-3)=a(1,2)+b(2,3)$$ and $$T(2,3)=(20-18, 34-30)=(2,4)=c(1,2)+d(2,3)$$ for some values $a,b,c,d$. Now set a system of achieved equations and then try to find these unknown values. Indeed, $$[T]_{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix} a &c\\b &d\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Okay, I see now, thanks!

Comment: @Alti: I am glad I could give you a light. :-)

Comment: Wait, this yields the wrong answer? The correct matrix is supposed to be (0, 2, -1, 0) where a =0, c = 2,  b = -1 an d= 0.